# Endpoint www. domain added fine but how to add non www to redirect to https://www

Tags: azure, endpoint, azure-static-website-hosting

I am quite new to Azure and I have made a static web page with literally just an index.html in the storage. I have setup the endpoint with a custom domain of www. and added the CNAME which works perfectly if I go to that domain url but if I do it without www. it directs to the 123 reg parked page. Any one able to help with how to sort this out? I have tired adding the domain to the custom domain tab without the www. but I get the error of cannot find the dns record CNAME for the domain but it seems I cannot add a CNAME record without a hostname.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add an _apex domain_. With these you usually have to use A records, not CNAME records. Check the documentation for the service you are using on how an apex domain is added to it (if it is possible).

Comment: @juunas thank you for the reply. I ended up fixing this by deleting it all and creating a web app instead and adding the domains that way.

Comment: Thanks for the update, JoeCold.  As mentioned in the doc, when you designate a custom domain as your app's default domain, requests to other domains are automatically redirected to the default domain. Only one custom domain can be set as the default.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-default#set-a-default-domain

Comment: This guide shows 3 options (ALIAS, CNAME, A) for configuring an apex domain: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/apex-domain-external?source=recommendations  -You may set up forwarding that you only configure the apex domain to forward to the www subdomain